# need assistance on mongoose model

Tags: database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to mongoDB and mongoose. But what I am trying to do is be  able to access the users I have stored in my database by their email, if a user was successfully retrieved the I will compare the password they wrote with the hashed password stored in the database

this is what I have for my Schema

**UserSchema**

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: { type: String, required: true }, //require makes it so that the fields can't be left blank
  lastName: {type: String, required: true},
  emailAddress: {type: String, required: true},
  password: {type: String, required: true}      
});
var User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

I am using the basic-auth package in my routes.js file in order to test this api in postman, this is the part where I am stuck, ***const user = User.find({'emailAddress': credentials.name, user.emailAddress} );*** I am having trouble putting together a query to access user email from the database

```
    //This middle-where function will authenticate users
const authenticateUser = (req, res, next) => {
  let message = null;

  // Parse the user's credentials from the Authorization header.
  const credentials = auth(req);

  // If the user's credentials are available...
  if (credentials) {
    // Attempt to retrieve the user from the data store
    // by their email (i.e. the user's "key"
    // from the Authorization header).
    const user = User.find({'emailAddress': credentials.name, user.emailAddress} );

    // If a user was successfully retrieved from the data store...
    if (user) {
      // Use the bcryptjs npm package to compare the user's password
      // (from the Authorization header) to the user's password
      // that was retrieved from the data store.
      const authenticated = bcryptjs
        .compareSync(credentials.pass, user.password);
```

in this express router I will be returning a user only after being authenticated

```
//GET /api/users 200, THIS WORKS IN POSTMAN
//This Route returns the currently authenticated user,     
router.get('/users', authenticateUser, (req, res) => {
  //within the route handler, the current authenticated user's information is retrieved from the Request object's currentUser property:
  const user = req.currentUser;
//we use the Response object's json() method to return the current user's information formatted as JSON:
  res.json({
    firstName: user.firstName,
    lastName: user.lastName,
  });
});
```

Can someone help? For reference this is my repo https://github.com/SpaceXar20/rest_api-mongo-p9

Answer (score 0):

here the way you find() is wrong
it should be either a callback or a exec() with async await.. this case just use callbacks 
so instead of this code,

```
const user = User.find({'emailAddress': credentials.name, user.emailAddress} );
```

use this code

```
    User.find({emailAddress:user.emailAddress},(err,user)={
      if(err) throw err;
      // do what you please
    if (user) {

      bcrypt.compare(password,hash,function(err,isMatch){
    if(err) callback(err,null);
    callback(null,isMatch);

});
    } );
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but I end getting an error, user not defined on postman

Comment: Could you show a snippet  of how you you used bcrypt as a callback?

Comment: ok .. I thought first you forgot to use the callback.. but I saw that u have used Sync() method in it.. but anyways try the callback here I have given.... check the code again .. I have edited the callback

Comment: Ah yes I have made some updates to my code on github

Comment: yeah.. try again  with bcrypt callback mate